# Linear model grid search in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to do a grid search using linear model in R. I have experimental data with periodic pattern and I am trying to fit something like:

```
lin_fit <- lm(y ~ x + sin(2*pi*x) + cos(4*pi*x), data = my_df)
```

I can try different combination of `sin` and `cos` and periods, but I wonder if I can automate this process i.e. select grid of `sin` and `cos` and periods and try them all. How can I possible feed it into `lm`?

Comment: One thing to note is there are special functions `sinpi` and `cospi` that would allow you to write `sinpi(2* x)` for example. To more closely address your question, I would wrap this into a function with two arguments and then use `combn` or `expand.grid` to generate the arguments, and finally use `lapply` to return a list of results.

Comment: What exactly is it that you mean by "combination of `sin` and `cos`"? Interaction terms like `sin^3 * cos^2`?

Comment: @Julius, something like `sin(2*pi*x) + cos(1/2*pi*x) + sin(8*pi*x) + sin(1/32*pi*x)` and so on. This what I had in mind initially, but I like your suggestion. All I need is periodic functions.

Comment: I think that first clearly specifying these possible combinations, periods, and anything else is an important part of the problem. Once we have that, it should be easy to provide a solution similar to what @lmo mentioned.